# Reference request : transposed matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra

It is known that if $A\in\mathbf{C}^{n\times n}$ is a square matrix then there exists an invertible matrix $P$ so that $A^t=PAP^{-1}$.
My question is if the space $X=\{(A,P)|A^t=PAP^{-1}\}$ has been studied, other than noting its projection on the first coordinate is surjective.

Comment: The natural first question to ask is whether the projection on the second coordinate is surjective over nonsingular matrices.

Comment: Of course it is, just take A to be identity.

Comment: Notably, $P$ is an invertible solution to the equation $A^tP - PA = 0$, which is an example of both a [continuous time Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) and a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).